# Download a small file in an Application-based thread or a Service-based thread?

Tags: android, service, process, android-asynctask, download

I'm fairly certain that it's standard practice to handle asynchronous file downloads using a Service and AsyncTask. That way, you can kill the originating activity and go on your merry way. However, when you don't need the lifecycle management, remote process communication, or other major features of a Service, it seems a bit overkill.

Since a Service is still a part of the same process and lifecycle of the overall Application, why not simply run a background thread within the context of the Application (vs Activity, although not necessarily within the extended Application class)? Is there any reason why this would be a particularly bad idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm fairly certain that it's standard practice to handle asynchronous file downloads using a Service and AsyncTask.

An `AsyncTask` is useless in a `Service`, as you have no reason to do anything on the main application thread in a `Service`. Use an `IntentService` for downloads, as it gives you a background thread, plus automatically stops itself when there is no more work to be done.

> why not simply run a background thread within the context of the Application... Is there any reason why this would be a particularly bad idea?

Because your app will be unreliable.

While a lot of people focus on the independent lifecycle of the service, that's not why you use a service for something like this. You use a service as a flag to the OS that your process is still doing something.

Once you are no longer in the foreground, Android can terminate your process, at will, at any moment. Particularly if there is a lot of memory pressure, this can be within milliseconds of your app leaving the foreground.

However, Android generally prioritizes terminating empty processes (ones with no running activities or services) and activity-only processes, ahead of processes that contain a running service. Here, "generally" means that processes with services will not live forever, but they are far less likely to be terminated quickly.

Hence, using an `IntentService` is signalling to the OS that you are still delivering value to the user (downloading the file) and that it should leave your process alone, until either your `IntentService` stops (because the download completed) or your service runs *so* long that it's probably lost its virtual marbles.

An `Application` is *not* a `Service`. Every process has an `Application` instance. Having a download be "managed" by an `Application` is pointless -- you may as well run a bare thread outside of any `Context`. And, most importantly, nothing tells the OS that you are doing anything meaningful, and so your process can be terminated as soon as you leave the foreground.

> However, when you don't need the lifecycle management, remote process communication, or other major features of a Service, it seems a bit overkill.

Writing an `IntentService`, outside of the manifest entry, is not significantly more complicated than writing an `AsyncTask`. Invoking an `IntentService` is not significantly more complicated than invoking an `AsyncTask`.

Comment: Thanks! Obviously, I was a bit confused. Totally forgot about IntentServices as well.